# How to close a popup-window by OK-Button

Tags: java, android

I just created a little menue in Android Studio but now I have the problem to close my last popup-window by clicking the OK-button.

If someone has an idea how I can close this popup-window, thank you very much.

```
package com.example.berni.myapplication1_1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * Created by Bernd on 02.04.2017.
 */

public class File_Open extends Activity {

  //      public File_Open mWindow;
  //      protected Context mContext;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.file_open);

    //  Start Fenster File_Open
    Button cc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_OK);
    cc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //   Here is the order from the OK - Button:
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_OK);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        //  Here I could start a new window: (it works)
        //  startActivity(new Intent(File_Open.this,Next.class));

        //  Here I want to close this popup-window (it does not work!!!)
        dismiss();

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      }
    });

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .5), (int) (height * .3));
  }

  private void dismiss() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Start by correctly identifying the programming language you are using. That is not JavaScript.

Comment: have you tried btn.dismiss();

Comment: What happens when you press "cc" button? From your code, it should call method ‘dismiss()‘.

Comment: your dismiss method is empty

Comment: where is your PopupWindow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlertDialog`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");

    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    Button cc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_OK);
    cc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .5), (int) (height * .3));
}

private void dismiss() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing some stuff. You created at the Activity level a dismiss method which is not from an Activity.
When you works with dialogs, the Dialog class has this method implemented.
When you call the dismiss method at the Activity, do nothing because this is not implemented at the Activity level.
If you need to end an activity use finish().

Answer (score 0):

Here you will write all the import statements.

```
public class BluetoothWindow extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_window);

        // here setting up height and width of the popup window.
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*0.9),(int)(height*0.8));
        
        // Attaching close button with function.
        ImageButton close_button = findViewById(R.id.close_button);
        
        close_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                closeWindow();
            }
        });
    }
    public void closeWindow(){
        this.finish();
    }
}
```